# получение видеопотока ip-камеры через opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

в чем может быть проблема. пытаюсь передать видеопоток с ip камеры

```
import cv2
stream = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://10.17.8.162:5556/video')

while True:

    r, f = stream.read()
    cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

в итоге в консоли получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\cam.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1144205/394322

Comment: а вы пробовали открывать стрим не через ваш код?

Попробуйте код как тут в ответе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942232/error-215-size-width0-size-height0-in-function-imshow